# I'm having hard time fetching data using request.POST.get()

Tags: django

I'm currently making a very basic dummy social networking site to learn Django, and I'm having trouble with request.POST.get() which is not fetching anything. As this way, I'm unable to have user inputs in my view.py. which means my site can't register any user. Please help me out as all of my further learning depends upon fetching user input. My coding is like (i know it's very basic and could look messy or somewhat outdated, sorry for that):

models.py:

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name= models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    flag = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

views.py:

```
def register_user(request):
    user = User()
    user.first_name = request.POST.get('firstName')
    user.last_name = request.POST.get('lastName')
    user.email = request.POST.get('email')
    user.password = request.POST.get('password')
    user.gender = request.POST.get('gender')
    user.save()
    return redirect('/login/')
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'signup'

urlpatterns = [
    url('^$', views.signup, name='signup'),
    url('^login/$', views.register_user, name='register_user'),
]
```

signup/index.html:

```
<form action="{% url 'signup:register_user' %}" method="POST">

<div class="name">
    <table class="nameTable">
        <tr class="nameRow">
            <td>
                <p class="nameCSS">First Name</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p class="lastName nameCSS">Last Name</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="nameRow">
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="input" name="firstName">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="input lastName" name="lastName">
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>

<div>
    <p class="text">Email</p>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="email" class="input largeInput" name="email">
</div>

<div>
    <p class="text">Password</p>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="password" class="input largeInput" name="password">
</div>
<div class="signUpDiv">
    <button class="signUpButton" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
</div>
```

(there's a lot more in index.html, but for better short post's sake I've included just a little of its code and yes, I'm not using built-in forms class to make this form, but I've made my own template which this form coding is in. Hope I could do this and the problem isn't there)

When this code is run, no data entry is made. Whereas, if I run this method from shell using static values, it works fine. Thanks in advance

Comment: are you using a form for this?

Comment: There's not nearly enough information here. Are you actually sending data in a POST? You'll need to show how you are doing that; presumably a template with a form, in which case you need to post that template, the URLs, and the view that displays the form in the first place.

Comment: Use modelform https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/ and form.is_valid to get & validate your inputs

Comment: Great tuto here => https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html

Comment: When you say - no data is entered, do you get any errors? (off-course you did not described  how you are trying to call your register_user function). 
use try/catch to capture errors.

Comment: yes, I've made a form myself which is in templates directory of my web app 'signup'. I'll edit my post to add the <form> part

Comment: How can you tell that the POST dictionary doesn't have any data? Do you get an error? Did you try debugging or logging? It seems strange to use the url `/login/` for registering new users. And setting a password like that will simply not work right. You can use `user.set_password(plantext)` to set the password.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should be using ModelForm for this scenario but I tried executing your code and it worked with slight changes.
Here are the changes as per my opinion:

**You forgot to put {% csrf_token %} in your template which will lead to the forbidden error during the submission of the form**

I have updated the template code with the csrf_token.

```
<form action="{% url 'register_user' %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}

<div class="name">
    <table class="nameTable">
        <tr class="nameRow">
            <td>
                <p class="nameCSS">First Name</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p class="lastName nameCSS">Last Name</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="nameRow">
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="input" name="firstName">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="input lastName" name="lastName">
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>

<div>
    <p class="text">Email</p>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="email" class="input largeInput" name="email">
</div>

<div>
    <p class="text">Password</p>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="password" class="input largeInput" name="password">
</div>
<div class="signUpDiv">
    <button class="signUpButton" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
</div>
```

**You can use just one view to handle GET and POST request**

**I have updated the views just for the sake of this example, however, make sure that you are encrypting the password before saving it (use Django's default user model) and use**

```
user.set_password('PASSWORD_HERE')
```

Updated the code for views.py

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.POST:
        user = User()
        user.first_name = request.POST.get('firstName')
        user.last_name = request.POST.get('lastName')
        user.email = request.POST.get('email')
        user.password = request.POST.get('password')
        user.gender = request.POST.get('gender')
        user.save()
    else:
        return render(request, "YOUR_TEMPLATE_NAME_HERE")
```

**Also make sure that your url name is correct i.e register_user**

I hope this helps:)

Comment: it's still not working. i don't know what's wrong with my code, but it doesn't work